# Javascript object class that on click opens window for colorpicking and on change replaces object background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have the following object class. getBackground method is setting the color value of the `input type='color'` equal to the object bgc property, then  opens the colorpicking window. After that i want to wait untill the user sets new color value from the colorpicking window and change object.bgc value equal to the new value from the colorpicking window.

```
function Textclass(id){
                this.id = id;
                this.bgc = '#ff33cc';
                var self = this;
                this.render = function(){
                    var el = $('<div/>');
                    el.attr('id', this.id);
                    el.text('change-color');
                    el.addClass('box draggable');
                    el.css('background-color', this.bgc);
                    el.appendTo('#container');
                    el.on('dblclick', function(){
                        self.getBackground();
                        self.setBackground();
                    });
                };
                this.getBackground = function(){
                   var color = self.bgc;
                    $('#colorp').val(color);

                   $('#colorp').click();

                   // this line initiates before the change of color picker value
                   self.bgc = $('#colorp').val();

                };
                this.setBackground = function(){
                   $('#' + self.id).css("background-color",self.bgc);
                };
            }
```

So i want something like this

```
this.getBackground = function(){
                       var color = self.bgc;
                        $('#colorp').val(color);

                       $('#colorp').click();

                       //wait for new value picked from the colorpicking window
                       // on button 'ok' clicked from colorpicking window get the new value and set object.bgc = this new value

                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here onchange event should be registered on the color picker.
Also I guess you are using HTML5 color type.

Please find the https://jsfiddle.net/rv5atgw5/.

```
function divColor(e){
    var val = event.target.value;
    document.querySelector("#divId").style.backgroundColor = val;
}
```

In your example, in getBackgroundColor API,
attach an onchange handler to colorpicker like this.

```
 this.getBackground = function(){
      var color = self.bgc;
      var colorp = $('#colorp');
      colorp.val(color);
      colorp.on('change',function(){
         self.bgc = $(this).val();               
      });          
      colorp.click();
 };
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: well I know that but I have to implement it in getBackground method

Comment: yea so far good i made it work but when i create for example five instances of the button when i change the color of one instance the other instances background is changed too

Comment: Case might all the 5 buttons have something similar may be id or class based on which handler is attached. In jquery if you just use chaining then it will apply attached function on all the resulted DOM elements like for each. Please check whether anything is similar.

Comment: well setBackground function is selecting elements by id and changes the background-color how multiple elements are selected

Comment: I guess here all the buttons have same id. If that's the case then when you use $('#btnid') it will return all the elements with id btnid.

Comment: i saw the issue with console.log(self.id);
It seems that everytime i click different button self.id adds the id of that button to its self. so somehow self.id equals to an array of IDs in the end